# Getting innertext of HTML tags using Regular Expressions

Tags: php, regex

I'm having trouble capturing this data:

```
              <tr>
                <td><span class="bodytext"><b>Contact:</b><b></b></span><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:Verdana;
  mso-bidi-font-family:Arial'><b> </b> 
                      <span class="bodytext">John Doe</span> 
                     </span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><span class="bodytext">PO Box 2112</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><span class="bodytext"></span></td>
              </tr>

              <!--*********************************************************


              -->
              <tr>
                <td><span class="bodytext"></span></td>
              </tr>



              <tr>
                <td><span class="bodytext">JOHAN</span> NSW 9700</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Phone:</strong> 
                02 9999 9999
                    </td>
              </tr>
```

Basically, I want to grab everything after "Contact:" and before "Phone:" minus the HTML; however these two designations may not always exist so I need to really grab everything between the two colons (:) that isn't located inside a HTML tag.
The number of `<span class="bodytext">***data***</span>` may actually vary so I need some sort of loop for matching these.

I prefer to use regular expressions as I *could* probably do this using loops and string matches.

Also, I'd like to know the syntax for non-matching groups in PHP regex.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're only interested in the text between the HTML tags.  To ignore the HTML tags, simply strip them first:

```
$text = preg_replace('/<[^<>]+>/', '', $html);
```

To grab everything between "Contact:" and "Phone:", use:

```
if (preg_match('/Contact:(.*?)Phone:/s', $text, $regs)) {
  $result = $regs[1];
} else {
  $result = "";
}
```

To grab everything between two colons, use:

```
if (preg_match('/:([^:]*):/', $text, $regs)) {
  $result = $regs[1];
} else {
  $result = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The seemingly arbitrary stack overflow response to these sort of questions seems to be "omg don't use regexes! Use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead!!". Personally I prefer not having to use external libraries for small tasks like this, and regexes are a good alternative.

A simple way to strip out all the HTML tags, which is one way to tackle this, is to use this regex:

```
$text = preg_replace("/<.*?>/", "", $text);
```

then you can use whatever method you like to grab the appropriate text content.

Non matching groups are like this: `(?:this won't match)`

Comment: So what is it? RegexBuddy gave me (?:this won't match) as PERL regex but there was no PHP option couldn't be sure...

Comment: PHP's preg functions use the PCRE flavor, which is an option in RegexBuddy.  nickf's answer missed the : before he edited it.

Comment: I believe you (and the OP) mean "non-capturing groups", instead "non-matching groups". A non-*matching* group would be something like this: "(X(?<!X))". ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [screenscraping](http://www.developertutorials.com/blog/php/easy-screen-scraping-in-php-simple-html-dom-library-simplehtmldom-398/), or you could use [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) as well after finding the info you wanted.